# upgrading to 18.04. How to continue after reboot?

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

My trusty old ubuntu pc aksed for an update today from 17.10 to 18.04 - and now I cannot continue.

The installation itself was started like all other updates because there was a message that there was now an update. The installation is simple because it runs by itself until "Restart", where I need to press "Restart".

The pc restarts, and now displays black screen with the following text:

> ```
> Ubuntu 18.04 LTS mikael-hp tty
> mikael-hp login:
> ```

I write the user name - and press Return.
Now it states

> ```
> password:
> ```

I am writing my password. I can not see what I am typing, but it must be good enough because now pops this text up:

> ```
> Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04LTS (GNU / Linux 4.15.0-Generic x86_64)
> * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
> * Management: https://landscape.canonical.com
> * Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage
>
> * Meltdown, Specter and Ubuntu: What are the attack vectors, 
> how to fix work, and everything else you need to know -
> https://ubu.one/u2know
>
> 0 packages can be dated.
> 0 updates are security updates
>
> mikael @ mikael-hp: ~ $
> ```

Before I have read it all through, the following appears:

> ```
> mikael @ mikael-hp: ~ $ [1186.109477] ACPI Error: No Installed Handler for Fixed Event - PM_Timer (0), Disabling (20170831/evevent-286)
> ```

What now?

How do I continue?

Comment: In general your upgrade seems to have worked fine, just the graphical login does not come up. Is it possible you were using some special graphics driver before (e. g. nvidia)?

Answer (score 0):

From this [ArchLinux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=234371) forum, you appear to be missing `fontconfig`. Try this command and you should see similar output:

```
$ apt list | grep fontconfig

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

fontconfig/now 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed,local]
fontconfig-config/now 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 all [installed,local]
libfontconfig1/now 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed,local]
libfontconfig1-dbg/xenial 2.11.94-0ubuntu1 amd64
libfontconfig1-dev/xenial 2.11.94-0ubuntu1 amd64
python-fontconfig/xenial 0.5.1-1build3 amd64
python-fontconfig-dbg/xenial 0.5.1-1build3 amd64
python3-fontconfig/xenial 0.5.1-1build3 amd64
python3-fontconfig-dbg/xenial 0.5.1-1build3 amd64
```

When I tested the **16.04** to **18.04** upgrade, 233 packages were removed. Some of the removals were anticipated such as `gksu` but others were not. This may be your case. Hopefully if it's missing you can simply add it with:

```
sudo apt install fontconfig
```

Additionally you should **not** have been prompted to update until **18.04.1** is released on [July 26,2018](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule). Normally **18.04** can only be installed by manually running `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`.

Answer (score 0):

On behalf of my pc - sorry that I didn't knew about that upgrade thing. The pc just told me upgrades available, and I responded with an upgrade click.

Back to my prblem:
If I add this `sudo service gdm restart`, my pc ask for my password once again, and then it opens.

But this circus is unbearable:
enter username;
enter password;
enter sudo service gdm restart; and
enter password

I just want my pc to boot automatically all the way when I switch on the power.

What to do?

Comment: The accepted answer to [Can't start ubuntu-desktop after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031948/cant-start-ubuntu-desktop-after-upgrade-to-18-04) also worked for this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033622/no-display-available-after-upgrading-to-18-04