# No access to desktop after upgrade to 18.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 18.04, restart

I can't access the desktop when I restart my PC after upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 LTS. It just keeps taking me to a command terminal. I will appreciate any form of assistance and help.

Comment: Try the answer in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031948/cant-start-ubuntu-desktop-after-upgrade-to-18-04).

Answer (score 0):

could you please login and run:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

to check if the update was crashed and try to continue upgrade process.

If this is not helping could you please checkout:

```
cat /var/log/boot.log | grep FAILED
```

Maybe we get some information there.

br
chris