# Cannot boot after a stopped upgrade 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: boot, upgrade

I have set the computer to notify me of new releases. Recently, it asked if I wanted to upgrade of which I said yes.

The process of upgrading online to 17.10 started and I could see
the activities from the screen. After some time, it just stopped. 
I gave it time but then realized that it had stopped, so I restarted it.

Even after restarting again and again what I get is as captured in
the image. I've tried restarting from previous kernels and all stops
as shown on the image.

What went wrong and what can I do to complete the upgrade? My intention was once through with 17.10 was to upgrade to 18.04.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Progress so far;** 
Problem partially solved after following the first answer > askubuntu.com/questions/641642/machine-does-not-start – @George Kostov and in the thread there is a suggetion by  @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy which is to run startx. Opened virtual terminal CNTR+ALT+F2 then simply typing startx desktop loads. All my folders and files are intact. My woes are not over yet because after restarting, it stops as it was doing previously and again I have to open virtual terminal and run startx. How shall I load starx automatically?

Comment: I think the last row in the screen is the key of problem. See that topic, but the bad news is thath maybe you gonna need reinstall > https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/machine-does-not-start

Comment: This is weird. The release upgrade notifier should only suggest direct official upgrade path and there is no such upgrade path from 16.04 to 17.10. Instead it should have suggested a direct upgrade to 18.04. Are you sure that the release upgrade targeted 17.10?

Comment: "It just stopped" often means that it paused to ask you a question. Restarting without answering the question would break your install quite horribly, often requiring a backup-and-clean-install. Alternately, the system may have aborted the upgrade for various reasons. All those answers would be in the logfiles in  /var/log. The question is really: Do you want to learn the skills to diagnose-and-fix the problem? Or are you looking for an easy solution? If the latter, then backup-and-reinstall.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The suggested duplicate cannot be applied here IMHO. The answers to the linked question expect accessible terminal.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, The setting was to check LTS versions only but I changed it to any new version simply because I wanted to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Comment: After much fumbling and going through several posts,  I did CNTL+ALT+F2 which landed me on command line from where I've logged in. Done ls and all the files are listed. From here where do I go to complete the upgrade?

Comment: @fotocity Please [edit] your question to add details and progress. Along with keeping the question and its potential answers tidy and organized, your question will get bounced to the homepage and hopefully gets more attention.

Comment: startx is not what you need, you need to bring up the default login screen. Try this answer to bring up the login screen and report back: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031948/cant-start-ubuntu-desktop-after-upgrade-to-18-04/1031955#1031955 in order to notify me that you need to try something else in order to login to the default desktop environment.

Comment: Thanks so much to all of you for the assistance. Special thanks to @ karel because that is what sorted out the problem. The desktop now opens  and I can now log in and all files and folders are intact . The first part  of the link did not respond but the second namely  sudo apt install lightdm  && sudo reboot  did it. Thank you.