# gdm3 doesn't working after upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10

Tags: upgrade, login, lightdm, gdm, 18.10

I was using gdm3 in Ubuntu 18.04, after upgrading it stopped working (Similar screenshot in [gdm3 does not start in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050672/gdm3-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-18-04)) I had no login screen.

Using tty I tried (from: [Can't start ubuntu-desktop after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031948/cant-start-ubuntu-desktop-after-upgrade-to-18-04)):

```
sudo systemctl start graphical.target
```

This worked for a while, the graphical interface was started, so for testing purpose, I closed my session and I was able to enter again, but after a reboot the problem was back again, so from tty I had to change gdm to lightdm. Is it worth trying to get gdm working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

Comment: @Madbyte glad that worked for you!