# Why won't my Ubuntu 18 laptop start up the desktop?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

I was having trouble using SSH with my gnome shell, so I decided to upgrade (`sudo apt upgrade`)my operating system after an update (`sudo apt update`) did not work. Then my terminal output indicated that it was unable to upgrade gnome-shell and gnome-shell-common because the dependencies were not met.

An article online suggested that I remove the information after `Depends:` in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` for those two packages, and I was dumb enough to try that. That step allowed me to force the upgrade, but I must have broken something as the GNOME desktop no longer launches.

I am able to get in to the terminal, but not my desktop. How can I get GNOME to launch again?

When I try to start my computer now, I get the following messages after the desktop fails to start.

```
7.162243] Bluetooth: cdi0: command 0xfc8e tx timeout
```

then my login attempt is interrupted by the following messages.

```
[  15.386381] Bluetooth: hci0: sending Intel patch command (0xfc8e) failed (-110)
[  15.386557] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[  17.402388] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc11 tx timeout
[  17.386394] Bluetooth: hci0: Exiting manufacturer mode failed (-110)
```

After that I am able to reach a command prompt.

I would be fine with removing bluetooth from my computer; I never use it.

At one point, my computer was also returning an error about `/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` being an invalid argument. I think that was after GNOME broke though. I copied the `gdm3.css` file from `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css to fix that error though.

Oh, and there was a message from the terminal about the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file needing a colon after an attribute, but I believe that was before I broke the OS. I edited the file exactly as it asked me, and the error went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to resolve this one.

I was able to get back in to the desktop by installing `lightdm`, logging in with that, and then reinstall `gdm3`.

**FROM TERMINAL=**

```
sudo apt install lightdm  
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

**REBOOT**

```
sudo apt install gdm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

**REBOOT**

```
sudo apt remove lightdm
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031948/cant-start-ubuntu-desktop-after-upgrade-to-18-04